# Shell Script loop

Tags: bash, perl, shell, loops, sh

I'm trying to get the below code into a loop where it runs over and over again while increasing the ./rundate????????.sh by 1 day

For example:
First it runs "rundate20170101.sh"
second it runs "rundate20170102.sh"
..
..
..
..
fifteenth time runs "rundate20170115.sh"

Trying to get the loop to end after 15 days then it goes to the next question "do you want to run the patch"

any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

```
yn() { echo -n "$1: "
       while read  -sN1 x ; do
           x=${x,}
           case $x in [yn]) break ;; *) : ;; esac
       done
       echo $x
       [ $x = y ] ; }

yn "Do you want to install the new update? [Y/n]" || exit
./install.sh
echo "Pick a rundate file: "
select x in ./rundate????????.sh ; do $x ; break ; done
yn "Would you like to run the patch? [Y/n]" || exit
./patch.sh
```

Just to clarify I'm trying to get this script to run from the start to finish. then loop back to the start but change the .rundate2070101.sh to rundate20170102.sh but the other questions still asked after the first loop.

If this can be better written in perl would love an example!

Comment: Get your script checked at [shellcheck.net](http://shellcheck.net)

Answer (score 0):

you could use regular expression inside loop for example :

```
select x in (\.\/rundate)[0-9]+\.sh ; do $x ; break ; done
```

hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I was trying to get the script to run in a loop but increase the rudate{date}.sh to increase by one everytime it runs over.